# How to block direct access to .html files? (.htaccess)

Tags: html, .htaccess

I want to block direct access to multiple files, but being able to access in index.html

For example: I want to block access to all the files located in "`http://www.mywebsite.com/pages`" such as "`contact.html`" "`about.html`"... and only be accessed by "index.html" (`http://www.mywebsite.com/`)

and if possible, to block access to images folder (`http://www.mywebsite.com/images`) but still being able to use the images in "index.html"

I want to redirect to home page (`index.html`) or send a 404 status code when these files are directly accessed... I have a 404 not found page called "`notfound.html`"

Files:

```
index.html
```

pages (contains few .html pages used as links in `index.html`)
images (contains images used in `index.html`)

Comment: If they are on your web site and the web site is viewed by the general public you cannot prevent stealing. All they have to do is look in the browsers cache, capture the traffic or just sent the right HTTP request to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : redirect on index.html instead of notfound.html

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html
RewriteRule .*\.html$ index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1.html
```

In images directory in other .htaccess :

```
options -indexes
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html
```

But why do you wish to do this? ;)

Comment: To prevent stealing.. why is everyone asking the same question tho?

Comment: Ummm... how do I use the first one?