# Handle Direct Access to .html files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, apache

Let's imagine I am creating a web app powered by AJAX. This means that visitors would only needs to load the root (or `/index.html`) then would only be able to access the other pages through AJAX. This is necessary as `index.html` would be a master page while the other pages would only loaded to `#content` in `index.html` using [ajaxify](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify) and [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/). The problem arises when someone visits a page like `http://example.com/blah.html` directly into the browser. This would render a page that is not only ugly, but also missing some vital information already present on `index.html`. As part of the challenge, I do not want to deny the user access to the page. Instead, I would like to redirect the visitor to `index.html?url=somepage.html` then load `somepage.html` via AJAX once on `index.html`. Since the script loads the page into `#content` and also updates the url, they would end up on `somepage.html` but now with a sensible page.

Here are some ideas (not solutions) that I could come up with.

- include `redirect.js` file on every page to check if that page was loaded via AJAX, then conditionally redirect the user to `index.html?url=somepage.html` but in the case the app contains way too many pages (well over a thousand and continually growing), there would be too much redundancy (inefficient code). Again, is this even doable? Maybe I'd have to build some script that would read every file on the app and include the said script before writing the contents of the file back... What a great solution!
- Use PHP to automatically include the `.js` file but the app needs entirely in HTML (that is, only `.html` files are accessible to the user) and only able to use PHP via AJAX (that is, PHP could be available for use on `http://example.com/` but not on `http://app.example.com` for flexibility purposes. The whole point of having an app written in HTML is to be able to use platforms such as Phonegap as a means of writing common code for non-web platforms, whereas the same code would be deployed on desktop when one visits through a browser). Is there a way one can dynamically include a file like `redirect.js` on every HTML page when the user visits?
- Use Apache (.htaccess) to automatically redirect to `index.html?url=somepage.html` but how do I do this? I have no idea. In fact, I'd need the exact code that would do this. Can one properly encode the URL to be able to handle situations where `somepage.html` has query parameters of its own like `somepage.html?key=value&another_key=anothervalue` in .htaccess? Note that the use of .htaccess is viable as users would not be able to enter URLs directly if they were the local Phonegap version of the app.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524637/how-to-block-direct-access-to-html-files-htaccess) but both the question and the answer given are a little ambiguous and the answer does not actually solve the problem presented here.

As I could see before finally deciding to ask, a lot of developers are struggling with a similar problem. Help us out.

Comment: It would be really helpful if SO forced users to give a reason for down votes.

Comment: Suggest you read up on how various single page app frameworks work. Beyond that this question is far too broad in scope as outlined in the [help]

Comment: Stick all your *control* files into a directory then deny access to that unless it's being called by XMLHttpRequest -  [for example](https://www.codespeedy.com/prevent-direct-access-to-php-file-content-and-allow-only-via-ajax-call/)

Comment: @charlietfl Any specific link that you'd suggest I start from? I am not creating an app, only gathering knowledge.

Comment: @charlietfl "far too broad" in that it leaves room for multiple solutions, not that the objective of the question is unclear or too wide to have a single straightforward answer, correct? I think it's unfair to say the question is "far too broad in scope". The scope of the question is only about redirecting a lost user, and I don't think that in itself is too broad. The only thing that is broad here is how the problem can be solved. Also note that your link to the help center doesn't explain why this question is too broad in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Add redirect for all path of site on start page need:
in **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]
```

the full path to the browser string remains
like:

www.site.com/index.html => load `index.html`

www.site.com/somepage.html?key=value&another_key=anothervalue  => load `index.html`

in `index.html` need get file name like this (**php**):

```
$file_name=basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);  // somepage.html
```

and all get parameters

```
$key=$_GET['key']   //value
```

in all another file need disable content if request not ajax / xmlhttprequest
like this:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){    
  exit;    
}
//content if ajax only...
```

Comment: While your use of PHP assumes that I will have my PHP files together with HTML, this still doesn't work because `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` does not return `'xmlhttprequest'`, especially when I make the request using ajaxify. This is a really odd behavior, though your answer is on the right path.

Comment: In principle, you can refuse Ajax check. Because .htaccess, does not allow the browser to load any file other than index.html

Comment: Well, that would mean that my whole app would consist of `index.html` only and not any other page. This is certainly not a desirable outcome.